# How can I call cool image library functions by using prolog?

Tags: c, image-processing, prolog, c-libraries

I am looking to build a system in which I am able to call Cool Image library functions (It's a C Language library for image processing tasks) by using Prolog.

There are functions in CoolImage Library such resizing an image, creating a mask etc. So I don't want to make any changes to those functions, it's just that by using Prolog I can call them and further use it for building a WIN32 API.

I would be thankful if someone can guide me regarding this i.e. any reference which I should refer or any way of implementation.

Comment: Are you referring to [CImg](http://cimg.eu/) ? Cannot find anything useful googling for 'CoolImage library'... but I know a bit of CImg, and could be interested to provide support to interface it to SWI-Prolog

Comment: Yes I am referring to CImg only, I apologize for incorrect information.

Comment: It's c++, then. Maybe this evening I'll try to craft a pack for CImg. Will let you know if it happens.

Comment: Okay,thanks for the information.
It would be of great help for me, thanks a lot for this

Comment: @CapelliC Have you got any references for me regarding this problem statement.

Comment: Still working on it, sorry... had problems compiling on Windows, and I would like the pack to be portable. Anyway, this evening will load a demo on github to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I've uploaded to [github](https://github.com/CapelliC/SwiPl_CImg) an example of a simple minded interface, running the [first example](http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html) found in CImg documentation (see [example.pl](https://github.com/CapelliC/SwiPl_CImg/blob/master/example.pl)) when passed as argument to the program.

It shows how to create objects and define methods that act on such objects.
Take a look at what the code does, and feel free to ask for problems.

*edit*:

Updated the git repo introducing modules for the interface predicates.
Now exposed members of `CImg`,`CImgDisplay` classes must be prefixed respectively by `cImg`,`cImgDisplay`, and constructors/destructors are named `new`, `delete`.

The file example.pl has been moved to [examples/getting_started.pl](https://github.com/CapelliC/SwiPl_CImg/blob/master/examples/getting_started.pl), and it's shown how to fetch images located relative to the source:

```erlang
    ...
    module_property(getting_started,file(ModuleFile)),
    file_directory_name(ModuleFile,ModuleDir),
    directory_file_path(ModuleDir,'img/milla.bmp',Milla),

    cImg:new(Milla,Image),
    cImg:blur(Image,2.5),
```

*edit*:
When you find you need to call a member not yet implemented, you should add it in your swipl_cimg.cpp, in the appropriate section (I mean, where you see the `#define PROLOG_MODULE className...` corresponding to the object you need), dereference the object(s) using the cast functions and call the c++ method. It's a lengthy, boring way, sorry but I don't know nothing better... To cover the full CImg library, a **lot** of work is required. So, attempt to implement - and carefully test - only what is needed...

It's useful to follow some convention: input parameters first, output last.

Comment: I understood the way you did the compilation and execution of the prolog and cimg. I just wanted to know, what approach should I use to call other cimg functions by using prolog with this approach which you have used.